What is the purpose of this proof of the Konig theorem?
"I am studying the König theorem on page 61 of Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic by Holz, Michael.
I understand that $f_{a,j}(i)$ is well-defined for $(a, j)$ and that assigning an ordered pair to a function uniquely, as assumed with $f_{a,j}(n)$ and $g_{a,j}(n)$, makes sense, but I don’t understand the sentences following that :


I don’t quite understand why the fact that the set of functions for $f_{a, j}$ and its restriction functions on $I_1$ is injective leads to $∑\kappa_i ≤ | ∏(\lambda_k+1) | = ∏(\lambda_k)$.

And if we confirm that each pair $(a, k)$ can be uniquely mapped to $f_{a, k}(k)$, we’ve verified that every element of $∑\kappa_i$ corresponds one-to-one with an element of $∏(\lambda_i)$, so doesn’t the $≤$ relation already hold? I don’t understand the reasoning behind partitioning the index set based on $\lambda$ to prove this."



Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in the post, especially mathematical information; particularly so when it is the image of text. Here is why

This isn't the proof of Konig's lemma. That's part b. This is part a.

The first inequality is just  the definition of $\le$... that there is an injective map from one to the other. The latter equality because, since $\lambda_i$ is infinite, we have $|\lambda_i+1|=|\lambda_i|$, so if $g_i:\lambda_i\to\lambda_i +1$ is a bijection, we can map an $f\in \prod_i \lambda_i$ to $f'(i) = g_i(f(i))$ and get a bijection to $\prod_i(\lambda_i+1).$
No we verified every element of $\sum_i \kappa_i$ corresponds to a unique element of $\prod_i(\lambda_i+1)$. The above argument depends on the fact that $|\lambda_i| = |\lambda_i+1|$, which only holds if $\lambda_i$ is infinite. The finite case needs to be handled separately.


why above proof argument prove with lamda+1 and not lamda?

@유준상 Because the injection they construct is to $\prod_i(\lambda_i+1)$, not $\prod_i\lambda_i$. They map certain components to $\kappa_i$ and since we only have $\kappa_i\le\lambda_i$, we can’t say $\kappa_i\in \lambda_i$, only $\kappa_i\in \lambda_i+1$.  Not sure if that answers your question…
